# Is it possibile to get all classes present inside a composer project?

Tags: composer-php

I need to get all classes that are present inside a folder and its subfolder. For example, with this tree

```
src/
├── Foo
│   └── Bar
│       └── Hello.php
└── Hello
    └── World.php
```

I would get a list of classes like:

```
Foo\Bar\Hello
Hello\World
```

Can composer be used to get this kind of list? Or, ... exists a way to get the list of all classes present inside a folder(src folder)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should run command:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

Next you could try this code:

```
$classMap = array_keys(require('vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php));
```